# Why is cv2.imencode('jpg', ...) seemingly changing the color of an image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I create and view a random image. Then, this image is encoded as a jpg file with opencv. However, after decoding this image the colors have been changed slightly. This behavior is not seen using png to encode. Can anyone explain why this occurs? Is it a negative result of the jpeg compression? Am I doing something wrong? Code sample below to recreate this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

random_image = np.random.randint(255, size=(4,4,3), dtype=np.uint8)    
cv2.imshow('Image', random_image)
cv2.waitKey()

_, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', random_image)
img_string = img_encoded.tostring()
npimg = np.fromstring(img_string, dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey()

# Does not happen with png
_, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.png', random_image)
img_string = img_encoded.tostring()
npimg = np.fromstring(img_string, dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Edited to add some 4x4 images.

Original:

[image: Original Image]

JPG

[image: JPG]

PNG

[image: PNG]

Edited again with 512x512 images

[Original 512x512](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnbzi.png)

[JPG 512x512](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr8gj.png)

[PNG 512x512](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PctJ.png)

Comment: Might the image have an embedded color profile that's not getting moved over?

Comment: Your image is only 4x4 pixels... barely enough for JPEG to get started when it uses 8x8 macroblocks.

Comment: @AKX I have not heard of that before so I am not certain. I doubt that would be in there though since I am just creating a numpy array with random ints to build the 'original' image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell if you increase the image size you will still see the same behavior.

Comment: JPG is a lossy compression. It can change colors slightly.

Comment: Why are you going to and from string as well? Have you tried removing that?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The to and from string is because I am streaming these images and need them in string format. I just tried removing that step and it acts the same. It must just be the jpeg compression. I am just surprised at how drastically the color is changed in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

`JPG` is a lossy compression. It actually works by modifying colours in a way that should be "unoffensive" to the eye. `PNG` is a lossless compression, so you get exactly what to had after encode/decode.

You can control how much `JPG` will be free to modify the image by specifying the `IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY` parameter like this:

```
cv2.imencode(('.jpg', img, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 90])
```

Higher values means less compression and result closer to original.  For example, `100` should be no compression at all and result identical to original.

Comment: I tried setting the value to 100 and the colors are still changing. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: Try 99,perhaps 100 is unacceptable for lossy compression

Comment: Still the same, the way it changes the colors it must be related to the compression. I will try to add images here.

Comment: Oh, just noticed that your image is 4 pixels. This is a really bad idea for jpg. Try creating large image divided into 4 random sections. If you don't know how to do this let me know

Comment: I am colour blind so I can't really tell :). I xcant seeany significant or detectable to me color change on 512 x 512 image

Comment: Gotchya, so this problem resolves itself as image size is increased? Larger images still see some color change but I guess that is expected.

Comment: You should probably read about how jpeg works to understand why the effect is so dramatic on 4 pix image. The idea is that the eye cant tell easily if small regions of the image are slightly shifted.

Comment: This is a good place to start... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Encoding

Comment: With 4x4 pixels, the image is padded to 8x8 pixels with zeros (==black pixels), which will reduce the average brightness of the compression block.

Comment: `@Moshel` I said the same thing about JPG compression in my comments before your answer!. Also JPG compresses in blocks of 8x8. So start with an 8x8 section and no smaller.

Comment: @JakobElias a quality of 100 isn't "no compression" as stated in this answer, but it's as close as you can get.  There might be other settings controlling [chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Downsampling) that would help too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your PNG image had the correct colors as in my case it was also affected. Anyway, this should work for any extensions.

OpenCV uses BRG instead of RGB, so it inverts the red and blue colors. To correct this, make sure to re-convert the image colors before encoding them:

```
correct_color = cv2.cvtColor(img_array , cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
encode_image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', correct_color)
```

Note that `img_array` is the NumPy array resulting from a cv2.imread()